# Simple DAX query which sums and calculates

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, tabular, dax

I have a SSAS Tabular Model in this format:

[image]

I need a SSAS DAX query which outputs the following format:

[image]

Does anyone know how this would be done?

I will then be using this in a SSRS report.

Comment: You have this tagged as both MDX and DAX.  Would an MDX answer be acceptable or do you only want DAX?

Comment: Also, can you post what you have tried? [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634396.aspx) has great documentation about DAX functions adn DAX query syntax.

Comment: I have not really tried anything, i can't really find anything online that shows an example of this.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/using-dax-to-create-ssrs-reports-the-basics/ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DAX/92740/  You may want to add some of these as calculated measures in your model if you can.  Otherwise, you can probably just write long queries to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer you can just copy/paste because I have no idea what your model or tables look like. You should be able to adjust the measures and query below to fit your model.

```
[ProductSales] := 
SUMX ( Sales, Sales[Quantity] * Sales[Price] )

[SalesMTD] :=
CALCULATE ( [ProductSales], DATESMTD ( DateTable[DateKey] ) )

[SalesYTD] :=
CALCULATE ( [ProductSales], DATESYTD ( DateTable[DateKey] ) )

[SalesMTDPrevYear] :=
CALCULATE (
    [ProductSales],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( DATESMTD ( DateTable[DateKey] ) )
)

[SalesYTDPrevYear] :=
CALCULATE (
    [ProductSales],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( DATESYTD ( DateTable[DateKey] ) )
)
```

To pull your information into SSRS (I'm assuming you know how to get to the data set creation screen):

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZE ( 
    Locations[Continent], 
    Locations[Country], 
    Locations[City], 
    Products[ProductName], 
    "Month Sales (This Year)", [SalesMTD],
    "Month Sales (Last year)", [SalesMTDPrevYear], 
    "YTD Sales (This Year)", [SalesYTD], 
    "YTD Sales (Last year)", [SalesYTDPrevYear]
)
```